# Creating an email sending command - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a command for sending an email automatically daily.

I'm creating the command like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmail extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'emails:send';

    protected $description = 'Sending emails to the users.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => "МГ 'Константин Величков', гр. Пазарджик",
        );

        Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function ($message) {

            $message->from('mg.kvelichkov@gmail.com', 'МГ "Константин Величков"');

            $message->to('yoannam1502@gmail.com')->subject('Оценки');

        });
        $this->info('The emails are send successfully!');
    }
}
```

And then register it in Kernel like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;



use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\SendEmail::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('emails:send')->daily();
    }
}
```

I'm listing all artisan commands and i can see my new comand emails:send - therefore its created, but when i try to run it `(php artisan emails:send)` i got this:

> [Swift_TransportException]   Process could not be started [The system
>   cannot find the path specified.   ]

What is the problem?

Comment: `$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();`

Comment: And i put that where?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Gmail is blocking sending emails or your environment blocks connection.

Go to [this address](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) to unlock your Gmail account. Also, check firewall settings on your server.

Comment: I unlock my account but that doesn't help. How can i check this firewall settings?

Comment: What environment do you use (Homestead, XAMPP or Linux/Windows server)?

Comment: XAMPP, but its on shared host now

Comment: Well, where do you get the error message (host or XAMPP)? If it's shared hosting and sending emails work on your local machine, I'd contact the support and ask them about firewall and open ports.

Comment: I'm getting the error on host, but I tested before making the command and the emails are send. Just stop working when i try to put it in a command.

Comment: Did you test your command on localhost where sending emails works?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Where does sending email code without using command work (localhost, shared host or both)? Where does command work (localhost or shared host)?

Comment: Without using command working on shared host. The command doesn't work because I always get this: `[Swift_TransportException]
  Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.
  ]`